# Highcharts-React returns Object and React gives error - React.createElement: type is invalid

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

I am using Highchart-React-Official to render charts in my application. Also, it's huge application so, we don't import anything, we use minified versions of plugins for the performance and security issues.

Below is my code:

```
const options = {
    title: {
        text: 'My chart'
    },
    series: [{
        data: [1, 2, 3]
    }]
}

const App = () => <div>
    <HighchartsReact
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={options}
    />
</div>


ReactDOM.render(
        <App/>, document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

When I run this, I get the below error in console:

**Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.**

[image: HighchartsReact]

When I console for the HighchartsReact, it is giving the below Object.

[image: HighchartsReact - Object]

I use unminified files for React and ReactDom and understand very well that When React creates an element, it has to be either String, class or function.

I also looked into Highcharts-React-Official, source code, it should deliver 'div' but in my case, it is delivering entire HighchartsReact Object with all of its a method.

I will really appreciate any suggestions to fix this problem.

Comment: What does your import statement look like?

Comment: Hi @Hima Chhag, Which versions of `react` and `highcharts-react-official` do you use?

Comment: @MarkSwardstrom, I don't import. I just use minified versions of files. So, it is available globally in my application.

Comment: @ppotaczek, Both of those are the latest. React - v16.9.0, Highcharts - v7.2.0

Comment: @Hima Chhag - Are you also using the latest version of the wrapper? Does your application work properly without the wrapper and Highcharts?

Comment: @ppotaczek, Yes, I am using the latest version of highcharts-react-official wrapper, which is - 2.2.2. Except for Highcharts, my application works perfectly fine. If I don't put Highcharts and just put simple Jsx with Div or H1 or anything else, that also renders fine. The only issue happens is with the Highcharts Wrapper

Comment: Thanks for the information. Could you reproduce that problem in some online code editor? You can start from: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-nx5id

Comment: FWIW, I had a similar issue go away after changing my imports from `import * as HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';` to `import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';`. No idea why they were originally being imported with `* as`.